# Using os.walk inside a Tkinter mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter

As the title indicates, I'm trying to use `os.walk` inside a Tkinter mainloop. I'm using Python 3.3.0.

Essentially, I have an interface that when you press a button, you then enter a **for** loop that iterates the elements of a list (for this case, they are archive names, that are later decompressed) and afterwards calls the `os.walk` loop to perform some comparison options. This wouldn't be a problem if I hadn't anything to show on the main window. Since I expect this to take a while, I was planning to add a pair of time counters to record and estimate the time it takes to perform the full operation.

I know that if I enter a **for** or **while** loop inside a `mainloop()` I would end up starving the `mainloop`, therefore the timers wouldn't be updated until the loop ended.
I also know about `w.update_idletasks()` but that only seems to update the stuff inside the loop.

I know that the best way to loop while inside `mainloop` is to have a function call itself recursively (either through a callback mechanism or a return statement). However, since `os.walk` is a generator, I don't know how to convert it to a recursive function.

Here is a snippet of the (simplified) code in question:

```
for file in ziplist:
    try:
        # some code in here

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(zipdirpath):
            for files in filenames:
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath,files)[len(zipdirpath)+1:]
                size += os.stat(os.path.join(dirpath,files)).st_size
                print(filepath)
                left.append(filepath)
        print(size)

        # some code in here

    except:
        # some code in here

    finally:
        # some code in here
```

I can convert (or at least I think I can) the first loop to something like this:

```
def callback(): # to be called by Tkinter
    def func(index=0):
        if index > len(ziplist):
            return

        # some code in here

        index += 1
        func(index)
```

But I'm slightly baffled on how to do the same with the `os.walk` loop. Hence, my question.

EDIT: I believe I may have found an answer. If I use `next(os.walk(...))` I can eventually get everything I would need (as a tuple). However, I would still like to hear some other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around this and I have a "solution":

First of, using `return function()` statements or just calling the `function()` ends up starving the event loop. So, I have to call all relevant functions recursively through `w.after` or `w.after_idle`.

Lastly, functions calling themselves involves recursion, which for some long processes might ultimately crash the program, although it seems that the Tkinter eventloop manages these things altogether differently.

---

Both these...

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)
```

...and these...

```
walk_object = os.walk(path)
def func():
    global walk_object
    try:
        dirpath, dirnames, filenames = next(walk_object)
        print(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)
        func()    # or w.after(0,func) or w.after_idle(func)
    except StopIteration:
        return
func()
```

...lines of code will output the same.